# Assigning a parameter to the greater of two numbers

Tags: recursion, prolog

I've written the following recursive function to assign a parameter to the greater of two numbers:

```
max(A,B,X) :-   
    A >= B,
    X is A.

max(A,B,X) :-
    max(B,A,X).
```

This works as expected but as a newcomer to Prolog, I'm hesitant to believe this is the most efficient solution. Is there a better way of doing this?

Additionally, pressing ';' after calling the function repeats it again. Is this correct behaviour?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems convoluted to me. Try something like

```
max(A,B,A) :- A >  B .
max(A,B,B) :- A =< B .
```

Though you might want to put some type checking in.

[edited to remove the need for a cut, and provide better support for pre-instantiated 3rd parameter.]

Another option, of course, might be something like this:

```
max(A,B,M) :- A > B -> M=A ; M=B .
```

This will throw an error is A or B is unbound, while the first example will work regardless of how it is invoked (so long as 2 arguments are instantiated). For instance, invoking it as

```
max(A,3,5).
```

yields `X=5`.

Comment: Thank you @nicholas-carey, that's far better than my solution. May I ask for more detail about why the cut is necessary? Even without it, I don't receive a second and false result.

Comment: without the cut, something like `max(2,1,X)` will give `X = 2` on the first success. Backtracking will subsequently yield `X = 1`. Further backtracking will then fail. With the cut, there is only one solution: `X = 2`.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong in saying I didn't receive a second and false result; which the cut does of course solve. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't. I just changed my code example to eliminate the cut and make the test explicit in each case, so as to allow for the possibility of the 3rd argument being pre-intantiated.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the built-in arithmetic "max" function? Z is max(X, Y). Or use constraints if you want to use the predicate in other directions as well.